# Custom stepper on Angular 4. I can't get content from child step

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to write my custom stepper for my project. I need this functionality

```
<custom-stepper>
  <custom-step>
    content which I cann't get
  </custom-step>
  <custom-step>
    content which I cann't get
  </custom-step>
<custom-stepper>
```

What I have now

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'custom-step',
  templateUrl: `
    <ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
  `,
})
export class CustomStepComponent {

}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'custom-stepper',
  templateUrl: `
    <div *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class CustomStepperComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(CustomStepComponent) _steps: QueryList<CustomStepComponent>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
      this._steps.forEach(tabInstance => console.log(tabInstance));
    }
}
```

I get 2 steps but without content. I don't know how I can get and put this content. Can you please help me.

Comment: Does the content show up in the view?

Comment: If I have "n" steps I get only "n" empty div's

Comment: try removing the `ng-template` wrapper from `CustomStepComponent` template. Does that change anything? what does `step.content` look like?

Comment: I tried, but nothing happened. I took this example from Material UI. When I try to render step with json pipe I get empty objects.

Comment: Take a [look at the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) for inspiration.